# Removing the margin From my Wordpress website

Tags: html, css, wordpress, margin

I have a Wordpress website installed "Quidus Theme" http://theme.socialflag.net/latest-free-wordpress-themes/.
There is a big unnecessary space from the right side which looks is very bad.
I want to remove this space and want my web pages to fit to the whole screen.
If there is something i can change in my CSS style please let me know.
One of my friend provided this code but I don't know what to do with this or where to put the code.

**Note:**  I want all my posts to fit to full width not only the page link i provided.

```
    <pre>

@media screen and (min-width: 1105px){

.site-content {
    width: 78%;
}

</pre>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change the css site-content in `media screen` and it will look like the attached image:

[image: Look images its looks good now]

```
<pre>

@media screen and (min-width: 1105px){
.site-content {
    width: 78%;
}

</pre>
```

Comment: I hope it is usefull to you

Comment: please double check your answer with the preview

Comment: – IsuruAb bro I not am getting you. What you say?

Comment: @chiragsolanki can you please tell me where to put this code.I am little bit familiar with html and css coding. It seems your code is wonderful. But i need some more clarification. I don't know what to do with this code. Also I want the same code for all of my posts.The code provided by you is only for [My One Page Click To See Page](http://theme.socialflag.net/latest-free-wordpress-themes/)  . I need also when i click any of my post also have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Undertake the following:

Override the `max-width` property in the layout to 100% (or if you'd like, you can look for the rule and remove it in your css

Set your div with id `content` to a width of 78%

[click here for codepen](http://codepen.io/repzeroworld/pen/WpKZPK)

Answer (score 0):

Use the developer tools in your browser (i.e inspector in Chrome or firebug in Firefox) to see where the padding is coming from.

Either the padding is applied to something other than the body, or the padding is applied to the body but is still overriding your CSS. For example:

```
body.class {
    padding: 20px;
}
Would override your CSS. or

body {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Declared after your CSS would still override.
I face same problem on my website http://calendarsnews.com/ But when I used this process after it solve my problm